# Can't generate plot in Wolfram Mathematica 8

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

I have this function: Plot[{(sin (x)), (sin^2 x)}, {x, -2*[Pi], 3*[Pi]}]

When i'm trying to execute this function in Mathematica, i've got only this graph:
[image: sin(x), sin^2(x)]

How can i set to see the lines of the graph in Mathematica? In wolfram alpha it's ok, here not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the correct syntax, try

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x]^2}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```